# How to get separate fields data with IF() statement in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the unpaid and partial amount separately in single query

```
select 
    if(i.status = 'unpaid', sum(i.total_amount), '') unpaid, 
    if(i.status = 'partial', sum(i.paid_amount), '') partial 
from {CI}invoices i 
where 
    i.customer_id = ? and 
    date(i.invoice_date) < '2014-01-01' and 
    i.status not like 'paid%'
```

But i am getting blank i think that is because i used `''` in if statement, i also tried with

```
if(i.status = 'unpaid', sum(i.total_amount) as unpaid, sum(i.paid_amount) as paid)
```

which is wrong because i can't use `as` in `IF()` condition. Can anyone please help me to resolve this query or suggest any alternative way??

Comment: @hjpotter92 can you please elaborate what you want to say, i have set the `decimal` data type for `total_amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
    SUM( IF(i.status = 'unpaid', i.total_amount, 0) ) unpaid, 
    SUM( IF(i.status = 'partial', i.paid_amount, 0) ) partial 
FROM {CI}invoices i 
WHERE
    i.customer_id = ? AND
    date(i.invoice_date) < '2014-01-01' AND
    i.status IN ('unpaid', 'partial')
```

Comment: ahh, now it's working but want to ask one thing, `SUM( IF(i.status = 'unpaid', i.total_amount, 0) )` is it mean `IF(i.status = 'unpaid', sum(i.total_amount), sum(0))` or `IF(i.status = 'unpaid', sum(i.total_amount), 0)` ?

Comment: @jogesh_pi You want to sum "after" filtering out the data, not while going through it.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
select 
    sum(case when i.status = 'unpaid' then i.total_amount else 0 end) as unpaid, 
    sum(case when i.status = 'partial' then i.paid_amount else 0 end) as partial 
from {CI}invoices i 
where 
    i.customer_id = ? and 
    date(i.invoice_date) < '2014-01-01' and 
    i.status not like 'paid%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cross join table to itself to get paid and unpaid in the same row:

```
SELECT 
    sum(iu.total_amount) unpaid, 
    sum(ip.paid_amount) partial 
FROM {CI}invoices iu
   CROSS JOIN {CI}invoices ip
where 
    ip.customer_id = ? AND iu.customer_id = ? AND
    date(ip.invoice_date) < '2014-01-01' AND date(iu.invoice_date) < '2014-01-01' AND
    iu.status = 'unpaid' AND ip.status = 'partial'
```